# Query to build Calendar table in DB2

Tags: sql, calendar, db2

The below mentioned query builds 'Calendar' table with 10 years data in SQL Server 2008.
I need such table be built in DB2. Please help me make this query executable in DB2  successfully.

Thanks in advance for all your help.

--- Query to build Calendar table with 10 years of data in SQL Server 2008 ---

```
create table TST_CALENDAR (Cal_Date DATE not null)
declare @SrtDt DATE, @EndDt DATE
set @SrtDt = '2011-01-01'
set @EndDt = DATEADD(yy,10,@SrtDt)
while @SrtDt < @EndDt
begin insert into TST_CALENDAR (Cal_Date) select @SrtDt
set @SrtDt = DATEADD(dd,1,@SrtDt) end
```

Thanks,
BauV

Comment: Hello and welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please be advise that this website doesn't work like you seem to think in the question above. Nobody will do your assignments for you. You need to show that you tried for yourself and ask help only if there are specific problems you are tackling or to improve your already found solution.
Also, post your questions in the clearest and cleanest way possible and try not to have spelling errors. I would advise you to edit your post. I already made some edits for you.

Comment: Which version of DB2?  Usually, I'd probably go with a recursive query, which would avoid multiple `INSERT`s.  Real calendar tables usually have _far_ more than just a date column - what other columns do you think you need?

Comment: @Bandreid - thanks for your help, I can not lose my job expecting others complete my assignments. I was trying to mention 'what I want to achieve', straight to the point. I will keep your suggestions in my mind about all of my posts with immediate effect. thanks once again.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse: We are using DB2 9.7. Yes, your expectation is correct, I need some more fields like - Week_Off_Flag,Holiday_Flag,etc. I mentioned only the bear minimum of my requirement in my initial post. Een recursive query will also help me. Thanks in advance, BauV.